# Why does FolderBrowserDialog keep crashing in Blazor Hybrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor-hybrid

I have this Blazor component used in Blazor Hybrid WPF:

```
@using DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
@using System.Windows.Forms

<MudText Typo="Typo.caption">@Label</MudText>
<MudPaper Style="display: flex; padding: 10px; margin: 5px 0 20px 0" Elevation="3">
    <StringTextField 
        BoundValue="@BoundValue"
                     ValidationAttribute="ValidationAttribute"
                     HelperText="@HelperText"
                     HelperTextOnFocus="true"
                     FieldInputType="InputType.Text"
                     OnValueChanged="OnValueChanged"
                     Label="@string.Empty"/>
    <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Folder" OnClick="SelectFolder" Style="width: 10%"/>
</MudPaper>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnValueChanged { get; set; }
    
    [Parameter]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string BoundValue { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string HelperText { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public object? ValidationAttribute { get; set; }

    private async Task SelectFolder()
    {
        var folderPath = await Dispatcher.CreateDefault().InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            using var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog
            {
                InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            };
            var result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            var path = result == DialogResult.OK ? dialog.SelectedPath : string.Empty;
            return path;
        });
        BoundValue = folderPath;
        await OnValueChanged.InvokeAsync(BoundValue);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
}
```

and from time to time it crashes when picking a folder (same goes for files picker). Try-catch does not help, the app closes silently. Any ideas why?

Comment: So what would be the right approach?

Comment: Not really, I need the full path

Comment: As per the title - I'm not in the browser, I'm using Blazor Hybrid in WPF, hence both native client and browser features are available. The problem is that for some reason those dialog boxes sometimes crash.

Comment: check the output window in VS. probably you will find some additional information about exception.

Comment: The app craches silently, I cannot check any exceptions. Debug in try-catch doesn't help.

Comment: Check the Windows Event Viewer.